# CORS error with @nuxtjs/axios but not with fetch() or vue axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I don't get any error **CORS error**  when I am using **fetch** or **axios** from `import axios from 'axios';` but I get one when I am using `@nuxtjs/axios` **this.$axios**

Any idea why ?

Comment: on client or serverside?

Comment: its an SSR app, I get the error on Chrome so on client I guess.

Comment: does this happen on dev modus on dev server or on productoin server with domain etc?